# Mutiny: build single Uni from other ones

Tags: java, mutiny

I need to return a `Uni<Page<QdCF>>`.

Here code:

```java
public Uni<Page<QdCF>> findByDataBaixaNull(Pageable pageable) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.sessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
    countQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(countQuery.from(QdCF.class)));

    CriteriaQuery<QdCF> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(QdCF.class);
    Root<QdCF> qdcf = criteriaQuery.from(QdCF.class);
    Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.isNull(qdcf.get("dataBaixa"));
    criteriaQuery.where(predicate);

    Uni<Long> countQdCF = this.sessionFactory.withSession(session -> session.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult());
    Uni<List<QdCF>> qdCFs = this.sessionFactory.withSession(session -> session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList());
    // how to build Uni<Page<... here?
    // wrong code -> return new PageImpl(qdCfs, pageable, countQdCFs);
}
```

So, PageImpl constructor is:

```java
public PageImpl(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, long total) { //... }
```

How could I build a `Uni<Page<QdCF>>`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like:

```
Uni.combine().all().unis(countQdCF, qdCFs).asTuple()
   .map(tuple -> {
      long l = tuple.get(0);
      List<QdCf> list = tuple.get(1);
      return new PageImpl(.....);
   });
```